# How to extract patterns from a file and fill an bash array with them?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

My intent is to write a shell script to extract a pattern ,using regular expressions, from a file and fill an array with all the ocurrences of the pattern in order to foreach it.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I am trying to do it using sed. And a problem I am facing is that the patterns can have newlines and these newlines must be considered, eg:

File content:

```
"My name 
is XXX"
"My name is YYY"
"Today
is
the "
```

When I extract all patterns between double quotes, including the double quotes, the output of the first ocurrence must be:

```
"My name
is XXX"
```

Comment: What about removing all the newlines, and then inserting the newlines only between `""` ? Also note that writing a parser with only regular expressions to handle escapes sequences is impossible.

Comment: `grep -Eoz '"[^"]*"' file`

Comment: With this regular expression the newline isn't considered. Like what I have mentioned in the post. Beside, I would like to know how to fill an shell script array with the output of a command like this.

Comment: `the newline isn't considered` - what do you mean by this? How is it not considered? `grep -z` should work.

Comment: It appears that this command doesn't work for a multi line pattern. The intent is match everything between double quotes. The command suggested only matches something if two double quotes are in the same line.

Comment: [No it doesn't..](https://repl.it/repls/WrongIncredibleTransformation). Ex. it matches everything between `"` no matter the newlines.

Comment: I am trying to do it work. Right now.

Comment: @KamilCuk : According to the GNU grep man page: `-z Output a zero  byte ... after the file name`.  Why are you using this?

Comment: @user1934428 The "output a zero byte" is `-Z`. From [man grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) : `-z, --null-data
              Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each
              terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of
              a newline.` when using with `-o` you can extract all data between `"` (side note, this is unrelated to the problem OPs is facing.. ; ) )

Comment: Just for the sake of knowledge. I was working on something else and just got curious.

Comment: OP: What are you actually trying to do?  It sounds like you're asking a question about a potential solution you've thought up rather than the problem itself.

Comment: Can you have escaped double quotes between the double quotes, e.g. `"foo""bar"` or `"foo\"bar"`? Are the linebreaks inside the double quotes `\n`s alone while the line breaks outside are `\r\n` pairs like you'd get when exporting CSV from Excel or something else? Can you ever have a double quote immediately followed by a line break as the first part of a quoted field or not?

Comment: @KamilCuk : Copy & pasting from my grep man page: `-z, --null-data ... Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each  terminated by  a  zero  byte  (the  ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.` _grep (GNU grep) 3.0_

Answer (score 1):

> fill an array with all the ocurrences of the pattern

First convert your file to have meaningful delimiter, ex. null byte, with ex. GNU sed with `-z` switch:

```
sed -z 's/"\([^"]*\)"[^"]*/\1\00/g'
```

I've added the `[^"]*` on the end, so that characters not between `"` are removed.

After it it becomes more trivial to parse it.

You can get the first element with:

```
head -z -n1
```

Or sort and count the occurrences:

```
sort -z | uniq -z -c
```

Or load to an array with bash's `maparray`:

```
maparray -d '' -t arr < <(<input sed -z 's/"\([^"]*\)"[^"]*/\1\00/'g))
```

Alternatively you can use ex. `$'\01'` as the separator, as long as it's unique, it becomes simple to parse such data in bash.

Handling such streams is a bit hard in bash. You can't set variable value in shell with embedded null byte. Also expect sometimes warnings on command substitutions. Usually when handling data with arbitrary bytes, I convert it with `xxd -p` to plain ascii and back with `xxd -r -p`. With that, it becomes easier.

The following script:

```
cat <<'EOF' >input
"My name
is XXX"
"My name is YYY"
"Today
is
the "
EOF

sed -z 's/"\([^"]*\)"[^"]*/\1\x00/g' input > input_parsed

echo "##First element is:"
printf '"'
<input_parsed head -z -n1 
printf '"\n'

echo "##Elemets count are:"
<input_parsed sort -z | uniq -z -c

echo
echo "##The array is:"
mapfile -d '' -t arr <input_parsed
declare -p arr
```

will output (the formatting is a bit off, because of the non-newline delimetered output from `uniq`):

```
##First element is:
"My name
is XXX"
##Elemets count are:
      1 My name
is XXX      1 My name is YYY      1 Today
is
the 
##The array is:
declare -a arr=([0]=$'My name\nis XXX' [1]="My name is YYY" [2]=$'Today\nis\nthe ')
```

Tested on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WeeklyBeigeExpertise).

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for, depending on the answers to [the questions I posted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562077/how-to-extract-patterns-from-a-file-and-fill-an-bash-array-with-them#comment99706022_56562077):

```
$ readarray -d '' -t arr < <(grep -zo '"[^"]*"' file)

$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[0]}"
"My name
is XXX"

$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]=$'"My name \nis XXX"' [1]="\"My name is YYY\"" [2]=$'"Today\nis\nthe "')
```

It uses GNU grep for `-z`.

Answer (score 0):

`Sed` can extract your desired pattern with or without newlines.
But if you want to store the multiple results into a bash array,
it may be easier to make use of bash regex.
Then please try the following:

```
lines=$(< "file")                   # slurp all lines
re='"[^"]+"'                        # regex to match substring between double quotes
while [[ $lines =~ ($re)(.*) ]]; do
    array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")   # push the matched pattern to the array
    lines=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}        # update $lines with the remaining part
done

# report the result
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "$i: ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
0: "My name
is XXX"
1: "My name is YYY"
2: "Today
is
the "
```